# Consulta de precio a una tabla que si hay precio en la otra tabla los muestre

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo 2 tablas, en una se registra el precio normal y la otra ofertas por tiempo limitado, trato de que si hay una oferta que este en el rango de tiempo, se muestre en una sola columna, pero no lo he logrado, en ambas tablas esta el id del producto.

He intentado así:

```
select p.valor,
(select sum(cde.valor) from s1_precioespecial as pe where pe.producto_id=p.id and curdate() between pe.periodo_inicial and pe.periodo_final) tarifa from s1_producto as p;
```

Solo logro verlas en columnas diferentes.

Habrá alguna manera de que se vea en una sola columna?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Saludos.**

Prueba lo siguiente usando [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull);

```
SELECT
   IFNULL(
      (
         select pe.valor
         from s1_precioespecial as pe 
         where pe.producto_id=p.id and 
            curdate() between pe.periodo_inicial and pe.periodo_final
      ),
    p.valor) tarifa
from s1_producto as p;
```

> Se asume que de cada producto solo puede existir **una** o **ninguna** oferta que coincida con la fecha actual.